# Why I got error on Array("a", "b", "c").map(x => x.toInt)

Tags: scala

Tried to get integers from a list of Array with letters. While I can use `"a".toInt` to get 97, why cant I use the map function on an Array to get `Array(97,98,99)`?

Comment: So I am a bit lost, do you want to turn an array of strings into an array of ints, or you want to turn an array of chars into an array of their ASCII codes? If the former, do you realise that not all strings are valid numbers, so what do you want to do? Do you want to just crash the program if there is no a valid number? You want to silently ignore the failures? Do you warn to preserve all failures? Do you want to stop at the first failure?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you can use `"a".toInt`? Because here a is a string and cannot be converted.

`'a'.toInt` on the other hand, works perfectly

Comment: You are right. I didnt notice that the problem is because of string type